# Why does this return [['a', 'b']], instead of [['a','b'],['c','d']]?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing freecodecamp's Bonfire:Chunky Monkey. I almost have the solution, but I can't figure it out why it isn't working. So my question is: "Why does this return [['a', 'b']], instead of [['a','b'],['c','d']]?

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  var array = [];
  var tmp = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < Math.floor(arr.length/size); i++)
  {
  for(var j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
      tmp.push(arr[j]);
    }
    array.push(tmp);
    tmp = [];
    arr.splice(0,size);
  }
  return array;
}
chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
```

Comment: Because there's only one `tmp`.

Comment: Did you mean [['a','b'],['c','d']] ?

Comment: @HashPsi moving tmp within the first loop does not fix it.

Comment: Just for fun: [babel/repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=false&playground=true&code=function%20chunk(arr%2C%20size)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Array(Math.ceil(arr.length%20%2F%20size)).fill(0)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.map((_%2C%20i)%20%3D%3E%20%5Bi%20*%20size%2C%20(i%20%2B%201)%20*%20size%5D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.map((%5Bb%2C%20e%5D)%20%3D%3E%20arr.slice(b%2C%20e))%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(chunk(%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%2C%20'd'%2C%20'e'%2C%20'f'%2C%20'g'%5D%2C%202)))

Comment: Just for fun v2: [babel/repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=false&playground=true&code=function%20*%20chunk(arr%2C%20size)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20while%20(arr.length%20%3E%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20arr.splice(0%2C%20size)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(Array.from(chunk(%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%2C%20'd'%2C%20'e'%2C%20'f'%2C%20'g'%5D%2C%202))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the length of `arr` on each iteration preventing it from executing the second time.
Besides, one loop is enough.

```js
function chunk(arr, size) {
  var array = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) {
    array.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));
  }
  return array;
}
chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are altering the length of `arr` within the loop.  As a result, the outer loop only runs once.  You need to cache this before you alter it:

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
    var array = [];
    var tmp = [];

    // save this, otherwise the 2nd iteration will not run at all 
    // because the new array length will be 2, making half of that 1
    var iter = Math.floor(arr.length / size);

    for (var i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            tmp.push(arr[j]);
        }
        array.push(tmp);
        tmp = [];
        arr.splice(0, size);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: An explanation on the downvote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
 var array = [];
 var tmp = [];
 var aux = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(arr.length/size); i++)
 {
   for(var j = aux; j < aux + size; j++)
   {
     arr[j] != undefined?tmp.push(arr[j]):false;
   }
   aux = aux + size;
   array.push(tmp);
   tmp = [];
  }
 return array;
 }
 console.log(chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 2));
```

PS: It works with even and odd number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Configurable chunk size example with a loop.

```js
function chunk(arr, chunkSize) {
  var array = [];

  for (var index = 0, arrLen; index < chunkSize; index++) {
    arrLen = arr.length;
    if (arrLen >= chunkSize) {
      array[index] = arr.splice(0, chunkSize === 1 ? arrLen : chunkSize);
    } else if (arrLen > 0) {
      array[index] = arr.splice(0, arrLen);
    }
  }
  return array;
}

var result = chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 1);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You don't need the conditionals, `array[indx] = arr.splice(0, chunkSize)` should work too.

Comment: Your code doesn't work if you do for example: `chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of answers with working codes, so I just answer the **why**.

You thought the outer loop iterates twice, because `Math.floor(arr.length/size)` is `2` at the beginning:

```
for(var i = 0; i < Math.floor(arr.length/size); i++) {
    // ....
}
```

However, `arr` is chunked in the first iteration:

```
arr.splice(0,size); // arr is ['c', 'd'] after this step
```

For the second iteration, `i` becomes `1` and `Math.floor(arr.length/size)` is actually `Math.floor(['c', 'd']/2)`, the check fails and the loop exits. So there **isn't** a second iteration.